# accessing _id from template event listener in spacebars #each loop

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

So I know that if I have the following html:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <ul>
    {{#each events}}
      <li>
        <h4 class="divEvent">{{title}}</h4>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

I can access an event's _id by using the following event listener:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click li': function( event, template ){
    console.log( this._id );
  }
});
```

But if my html looks like this:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  <ul>
    {{#each year in getYears}}
      <li>
        <h2>{{year}}</h2>
      </li>
      <ul>
        {{#each monthNumber in (getMonths year)}}
        <li>
          <h3>{{monthName monthNumber}}</h3>
        </li>
        <ul>
          {{#each event in (getEvents monthNumber year)}}
            <li class="eventLi">
              <h4>{{event.title}}</h4>
              <div>{{dayOfWeek event.start}}</div>
            </li>
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

then how can I access an event's _id when I click on an .eventLi?

this._id does nothing for me...

I'm sure this is obvious but I'm just learning all this and I have been stuck on this one for a while. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I suspect it will be `this.event._id` instead because of `#each event in...` instead of just `#each event`. When in doubt, `console.log(this)`

Comment: unfortunately that does not work for me. I did as suggested and i get: console.log(this) // {main: function}

Comment: did you try 'click .eventLi' : function() ?

Answer (score 1):

With Blaze the simple pattern to solve this is usually to put the part inside your loop into a separate template so that you can unambiguously attach events there. (Your template has multiple `<li>` tags for example)

Instead of:

```
{{#each event in (getEvents monthNumber year)}}
  <li class="eventLi">
    <h4>{{event.title}}</h4>
    <div>{{dayOfWeek event.start}}</div>
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

have:

```
{{#each event in (getEvents monthNumber year)}}
  {{> oneEvent}}
{{/each}}
```

Then:

```
<template name="oneEvent">
  <li class="eventLi">
    <h4>{{event.title}}</h4>
    <div>{{dayOfWeek event.start}}</div>
  </li>
</template>
```

Now attach your events to the inner template:

```
Template.oneEvent.events({
  'click li'( event, template ) {
    console.log( this._id );
  }
});
```